# Define a row to be the one that names the columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has this structure :

```
             1          2       3
1          url  parameter  method
2  patientFull         63     GET
```

What should I do to be able to get the row 1 as the row that names the columns?

The result I try to get :

```
           url  parameter  method
1  patientFull         63     GET
```

Comment: read the file with `header=1` , if you are reading from a file

Comment: I have a file that I convert into a dataframe and create multiple sub-dataframes from it, that's why I have these `1`,`2`,`3` as column names. Unless there's a function that's `read_dataframe(header=1)`, I don't see how to do it

Comment: try: df = df.T.set_index([0]).T

Comment: @chuni0r what is the .T doing?

Comment: transpose the dataframe which is needed for set_index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
df_new=pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[1:].reset_index(drop=True).values.tolist(),
         columns=df.iloc[0]).rename_axis(None,axis=1)
print(df_new)
```

---

```
          url parameter method
0  patientFull        63    GET
```

Comment: Just to know, is there any ways of doing this without having to create a new dataframe? I'm just wondering if creating new dataframes will slow down my program.

Comment: @firefrost I will try to check if there is and get back to you on this if I find any

Comment: thanks, don't worry if there's no ways, it's just personal curiosity at this point :)

Comment: `df.T.set_index(1).T
`

Comment: @firefrost you can try the above :)

Comment: @firefrost so: `df.T.set_index(1).T.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis(None,axis=1)` will be matching your output. :) cant believe I didnt think of this. :D , you can ask chuni0r  to post an answer and accept it. :) Cheers..!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
df.index = range(len(df.index))
```

Comment: it gives me :
 `1          url  parameter  method
1          url  parameter  method
2  patientFull         63     GET`